# Why adding a get parameter forces middleware execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I have got a middleware like this

```js
// route middleware to verify a token
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

  console.log(req.baseUrl);

  // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
  var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

  // decode token
  if (token) {

    // verifies secret and checks exp
    jwt.verify(token, app.get('superSecret'), function(err, decoded) {
      if (err) {
        return res.json({
          success: false,
          message: 'Failed to authenticate token.'
        });
      } else {
        // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
        req.decoded = decoded;
        next();
      }
    });

  } else {

    // if there is no token
    // return an error
    return res.status(403).send({
      success: false,
      message: 'No token provided.'
    });

  }
});
```

This route **http://localhost:8080/verifyAccount** doesn't responds as `No token provided`

```
app.get('/verifyAccount', function (req, res) {
  res.json({ message: 'Welcome to verify account!' });
});
```

But the following route **http://localhost:8080/verifyAccount?id=123** does:

```
app.get('/verifyAccount/:id', function (req, res) {
  res.json({ message: 'Welcome to verify account!' });
});
```

The middleware code is at the bottom in the code file and the get paths are upwards

What is that concept behind?

> Why adding a get parameter forces middleware execution?

Just found that if I call it like this **http://localhost:8080/verifyAccount/id=123**, it properly returns `Welcome to verify account!`

Comment: I have setup a very basic example (only giving console.log output for each route and the middleware). I can see that the Middleware is never called. It is only called if the request has "dripped" through to it for an unknown route. Something else must be wrong with your code.

Comment: Ah, there is your error. The request with query parameter `?id=123` does not match with `/:id`. It should be `verifyAccount/123` instead

Comment: @devnull69 If my param name is `p1` then how will I call it?

Comment: The same. The position determines the parameter, not the name. The name is only used inside your node code to reference the parameter

Comment: @devnull69 In case of multiple params, I mean how do you setup multiple params?

Comment: You'd have multiple slashes like `verifyAccount/:id/:otherParameter` which would be called using `verifyAccount/123/234`

Comment: @devnull69 You made my day boss :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the issue was in the way by which the route was getting called. Thanks to [Thomas Theiner](https://twitter.com/devnull69) for the help.

The request with query parameter `?id=123` does not match with `/:id`. It should be called as `verifyAccount/123` instead.

> Since, the route `?id=123` did not matched any of the path. Hence, was finally reaching the `middleware` for execution

The **position determines the parameter**, not the name. The name is only used inside node code to reference the parameter.

For multiple parameters, we'll have multiple slashes like `verifyAccount/:id/:otherParameter` which would be called using `verifyAccount/123/234`